# OnChildClickListener is not working when using spinner as a child of the group inside expandablelistview

Tags: java, android, android-layout, clicklistener

I have a Expandablelistview where i am showing        child row, with two spinner, one edittext and an imagebutton. My requirement is to get the childrens each component id and do some operation on those component. Suppose, when clicking on add icon, it should add another child row to the same group. I have spend almost two days, not getting any solution or root cause why its behaving in this manner. Please anyone have any suggestiong  or idea, would be highly appreciated.

```
expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView expandableListView, View view, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext()," Child is clicked." ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
});
```

this is the child_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ecf4ee"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="com.esspl.eportal.TimeEntryChildviewActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/addIconId"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:background="@drawable/add_icon" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/devTypeId"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/devTypeId"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/devTypeId"
        android:background="#e2f70a"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:hint="0.00"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:nextFocusRight="@drawable/add_icon"
        android:textAlignment="textStart" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/devTypeId"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/projectTypeId"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/projectTypeId"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:entries="@array/development_type"
        android:layoutDirection="ltr" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/projectTypeId"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:dropDownHorizontalOffset="15dp"
        android:entries="@array/project_type"
        android:layoutDirection="ltr" />

    enter code here

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Well add another child. What is the problem? Somewhere in your code you defined the other childs. Thats the place to be.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But i want to add child when the onChildClickListener is invoked. Dont know why its not getting called, when spinner component is available in child list.

Comment: `But i want to add child when the onChildClickListener is invoked.` Yes i understood that already of course. `Dont know why its not getting called, ` You mean your on click listener? You did not tell that before. Should not you have started with that?

Comment: Yeah, i missed to mention that onChildClickListener was not getting called. Do you have any idea, why its not getting invoked, when the spinner are present. Can you please help with any suggestion.

Comment: Try to add this to your spinners: `android:focusable="false"
android:clickable="true"`

Comment: Its not working. Let me explain you something about my code. In that child row i have one two spinner, edittext and an add icon image inside linearlayout horizontaly. when i am clicking on the add icon, it should fire the onChildClickListener, as it is a child the expanded group view. But when i am removing those two spinner and edittext, the click event is happening. Any idea, why does it happen like this? Thanks for you patience.

Answer (score 0):

```
  the onChildClikListener was not getting called because of this code 
           android:entries="@array/development_type" ,
```

removing the above line code from 
spinner worked for me. But how to set values to the spinner dynamically in backend instead of using ArrayAdapter. What i guess is, array is the problem for spinner inside expandablelistview, but not sure.